# Third div after two consecutive divs

Tags: html, css

I am developing a web page and I have use two divs side by side to each other so that they both appear in one line. Now I want to place third div of navigation bar below to these divs but it occurs in between both of these. When I placed this navigation bar without div it is occured at top of the page.How can I fix this problem? I am new to html and css.
My code is:

```html
<body>
  <div style="float: left; margin: 0px; width: 200px">
    First div
  </div>
  <div style="float: right; margin: 0px; width: 200px">
    Second div
  </div>

  <div>Third div</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should avoid using inline styling. CSS is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that the third `div` takes all the remaining on the current “line” by default…
As your other `div`s are `float`ed on each side, it takes the space between them.

An easy way to avoid that is to use `clear: both` on your third `div`.

Plus, I removed all your inline styling and used CSS instead, and some other styling to make the snippet more visual:

```css
div { /* ADDED to make it visual */
  border: 2px solid #ccc; 
  padding: 4px;
}

.w200 { /* Used for common styling for div1 and 2 */
  margin: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}

#div1 {
  float: left;
}

#div2 {
  float: right;
}

#div3 { /* To move the third on a new "line" */
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="w200">First div</div>
<div id="div2" class="w200" >Second div</div>
<div id="div3">Third div</div>
```

Of course, you could change the width of the third `div` if you want to.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to the third div :

```
<div style="clear:both">Third div</div>
```

When you use float, you always have to use clear style to fix display issues.
But you have other alternative such ass Css grid, flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use break tag`<br>`  if you want to put that one next line

Answer (score 0):

Just simply clear the floating on the third div

```
<div style="float: left; margin: 0px; width: 200px">First div</div>
<div style="float: right; margin: 0px; width: 200px">Second div</div>
<div style="clear:both">Third div</div>
```

Better NOT to use inline CSS, and try to use flex or grid for layout

Comment: *"Better NOT to use inline CSS"*. So why using it?

Comment: @TakitIsy I used in my answer because it based on Itstudent 's example code.

Comment: Thank you for help. Your answer of clear: both also works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the answer you are looking for

```css
.third-div {
clear: both;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="float: left; margin: 0px; width: 200px">
    First div
  </div>
  <div style="float: right; margin: 0px; width: 200px">
    Second div
  </div>

  <div class="third-div">Third div</div>
</body>
```